# Customize the behavior of the facebook like button, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like

I have this question: I have the plain iframe facebook like button on my site and I hacked the url inside the tag so that it always points to the specific link I want it to point. BUT, when I see the "like" in facebook.com, it (1) picks a seemingly random image for the "like" and (2) the title of the "like" is always the same, i.e. the site name!

How can I have a versatile button that can result to a proper "like"? 
When my visitors click on it, I want their facebook timeline to show the image I choose and the title I choose.

I use rails, I have a custom authentication (no omniauth).
So, can I use opengraph, graph API with my custom authentication ? Do these things work with just cookies?
Should I put the title and the image I want to go to the timeline is some specific tags?

Let me just remind you that in rails, the < head > content seems not be able to change, as the layout template is specified once.

- - twitter API worked seamlessly BTW.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your page to conform to the [Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/). That's a fancy way of saying that you need to put some new meta tags in your document's head: once you do, your like button will pick it up automatically.

Though you generally define content in head once, you can still add content into it later. Instance variables from your views will be loaded into the template, so you could do something as easy as:

```
application.html.erb
<head>
<%= @stuff %>
</head>

view.html.erb
<% @stuff = "<meta ...>" %>
```

This is not exactly extensible or automatic though. At the risk of self-aggrandizement, I wrote a blog post discussing how to do this with a concern, so [check it out if you're interested](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/07/12/rails-concerns-iii-metatags/).

Comment: thanks!
used the gem in the show controller, the html appears to be changed, but in the end, when the user likes the page, in facebook all I can see is "User liked Site-Name"...

All I wanted is have this effect: [link](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-optimize-for-facebooks-new-like-functionality-66318) :(:(